# Saving WordPress Secret Keys to a variable in PHP

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to work with WP API to generate the random keys, [SEE HERE](http://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/), but I cant seem to find a way to retrieve the keys and store them into a variable.

I tried:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/');
```

but its unreliable, sometimes it returned 3 sets of keys sometimes 5,6,7 its random instead of the 8 it should.

Same thing happens using cURL:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/');
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

If someone could shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off set [`allow_url_include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) to true.  Also, understand the [implications this can have on security](http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/tests/allow_url_include.html).

Then use require or include.

```
include('http://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/');

echo AUTH_KEY;
```